# Select the most popular month

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my sample data. I want to  select the most popular month for borrowing.

[image]

This is what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(borrowdate) 
AS MostPopularMonth
FROM borrower 
GROUP BY borrowdate
ORDER BY borrowdate DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use `select top (1)`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) YEAR(BorrowDate), Month(BorrowDate), COUNT(*) AS MostPopularMonth
FROM borrower 
GROUP BY YEAR(BorrowDate), Month(BorrowDate)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

If there are ties, this returns an arbitrary matching row.  If you want all of them, use `TOP (1) WITH TIES`.

Comment: This definitely helped! But what if I wanted the month in a specific year for example? Would I then introduce a WHERE statement?

Comment: @Chevo1 yes, or use a HAVING statement

Comment: @Chevo1 . . . You would use a `WHERE` clause.  You want to filter before the aggregation.

Comment: Thank you. I've gone ahead and did SELECT TOP (1) Month(BorrowDate) AS MostPopularMonth
FROM borrower 
WHERE YEAR(BorrowDate) = '2017'
GROUP BY Month(BorrowDate)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;